# Test Flight and titanium , publishing development profile

Tags: titanium, ipa, testflight

To publish an IPA

I go to publish -> Distribute ad hoc/enterprise -> and then I publish the app

However, I can only publish an IPA with a distribution profile, this means I don't get any debugging on my phone.

How can I publish distributed profiles on test flight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

For ANYONE having this problem (i.e. being able to use a development certificate instead of production), follow the following steps.

---- Downgrade your ITunes VERSION to 11.1.5, otherwise it will complain when you try to do an iTunes sync that iTunes doesn't have enough memory!! (Titanium need to fix this!)

```
1) Download 11.1.5 from here http://mac.filehorse.com/download-itunes/4050/

2) Go to Applications, and Delete itunes... If you get an error message saying something like "This app is require by OSX" just go to Get Info > Sharing & Permissions > Everyone ... it has to say Read & Write.

3) Install the itunes you just downloaded

4) Open it (You might need to hold you "alt" key while opening so you can create a new library (11.2 changed something in your library that is not compatible with 11.1.5)
```

Then publish app USING ITUNES SYNC. (this is the ONLY way to get the development .IPA)

The app will now be in your app folder within iTunes.

You will now be able to upload your app onto test flight - a development version using a development APNS certificate. Also because it is in development mode, means that you will be able to see all error problems either through Xcode or Iphone configuration. If you publish an ad-hoc system based on production, it will not print out any Ti.App.Info etc commands in the device console.

Hope this helps! :)